# Firebase setvalue DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen other posts but it seems none of the solution fits my issue. The error is at the method `FirebaseRef.setValue()`

I'm trying to save data into to a `Firebase server`. At first I thought the error was because I tried to save the data as a custom object, then I tried to save it as a basic hash (I followed the tutorial in [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#152) link)

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Database Connection, if no connection or what not, exception will be here
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Log.d(DBTAG, mDatabase.toString());

            // 'child database'
            mBooksDatabase = mDatabase.child("books");
            mCurrentUser = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserEmail);

            // address to upload the book, later we can call newBookRef.getKey() to get the ID
            // and use the ID to indicate the relationship between the owner and the book
            final DatabaseReference newBookRef = mBooksDatabase.push();
            try {
                Map<String, String> mBookTest = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mBookTest.put("ISBN", "9781566199094");
                mBookTest.put("title", "Book of Love");
                newBookRef.setValue(mBookTest, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                        if (firebaseError != null) {
                            Log.e(DBTAG, "Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                        } else {
                            Log.d(DBTAG, "Data saved successfully.");
                            // update the 'owns' list in user's data
                            final String bookRef = newBookRef.getKey();
                            mCurrentUser.child("owns").child(bookRef).setValue("1");
                            //TODO: we can use this to count how many of the same books an user has
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (DatabaseException e){
                Log.e(DBTAG, "Error occurred", e);
            }
            // if owner is desired in book, we can modify this part

            return true;
        }
```

Error message:

```
09-26 20:37:12.631 5091-5399/bookjobs.bookjobs D/DB in BookController: https://bookjobs-6c56f.firebaseio.com
09-26 20:37:12.641 5091-5399/bookjobs.bookjobs E/DB in BookController: Error occurred
                                                                       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class bookjobs.bookjobs.BookController$UploadBookTask$1
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakk.zzbq(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakn.zzbr(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at bookjobs.bookjobs.BookController$UploadBookTask.doInBackground(BookController.java:59)
                                                                           at bookjobs.bookjobs.BookController$UploadBookTask.doInBackground(BookController.java:30)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-26 20:37:15.831 5091-5169/bookjobs.bookjobs W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: you don't need to use AsyncTack for doing firebase operations, firebase is already optimised and every network related operations run on the background thread.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get that error message from writing a HashMap. Can you double-check it's correct given your code sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completion listener on your call to `setValue()` is from the legacy 2.x.x SDK: [Firebase.CompletionListener()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_completionlistener_methods).  You must use the completion listener from the new 9.x.x SDK, [DatabaseReference.CompletionListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener).

The two SDKs are not compatible. You should use the new SDK exclusively.  Update your `build.gradle` to remove:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.x.x'
```

See the [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) for more details.

Comment: Good catch qbix! embarrassingly  enough both Michael and myself overlooked that. Thanks for helping other Firebase developers!